# Adding controls programmatically in UITableViewCell in static UITableView

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a static `UITableView` to which I am populating through NSDictionary in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
 NSString *key = [sectionKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
 NSArray *contents = [sectionContents objectForKey:key];
 NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil)
 {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }

 [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
```

Thinks working well, I also need to add controls to tableviewcells and every cell has different controls. When I programmatically add UITextField to cell1 the view after running is fine till 5 sections, but when I scroll my tableview further down, the cell of section 6 also gets a UITextField control. Same is happening with UIDatePicker, that first 5 sections of my tableview are fine but on scrolling the tableview the last two sections also get the UIDatePicker control.

Note: I have nine sections in table view each having one cell with the exception of first two sections that contain two cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understood:

The layout of your cells is getting messed up and controls from one cell go to the other one.

What I suggest:

It is a common problem, I faced it a while ago and it was extremely frustrating. After a few hours of googling I found a solution: Use different cell identifiers for cells with different controls.

Example:

5 cells: 2 cells with only a UITextField, 1 cell with UITextField and a UILabel and 2 cells with UIImageView. Use 3 different cell identifiers. 1 for the cells with only a UITextField, 1 for the cells with UIImageView and 1 for the cell with UITextField and a UILabel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am creating cells dynamically, then how to assign them an identifier, would the assigning of identifier and creating of controls both happen in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes, just change the `CellIdentifier` value to whatever you need